# how to keep a windows application alive in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, keep-alive

I have an application with the following code in my main function:

> var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback_f, null,
>   TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(srcInterval));

Okay this actually works but ONLY when I put something to keep my application alive like `console.readkey()` or an infinite while loop:

```
while (true) 
{

}.
```

The infinite loop is not an option for me as it is too time consuming. The thing is I can not use the `console.readkey` function either because it's a Windows.forms application with no forms in it. (i.e. when I run it as a console application and put a `console.readkey()` method at the end it works. However I want to avoid the showing of the black window, it's an application with no interface which runs in the background). Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Could you use Thread.Sleep(...) and Thread.Join(...)?

Comment: You'll need to document how you intend to terminate your program.  If you don't know then you probably ought to consider a service.

Answer (score 0):

try to use method [Thread.Join();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx)

Comment: @Dex: You are launching a timer and doing nothing on the main thread.  Why don't you just have the main thread do the work in an infinite loop and `Sleep(srcInterval)` in between tasks?

Comment: @Ed S. Wouldn't his be too CPU consuming and heavy on resources?

Comment: @Dex: No.  `Sleep()` will yield your CPU time to other processes. What do you think the Timer is doing?  Even a `Sleep(1)` will turn your overly aggressive `while(true)` loop into something which takes very little CPU in and of itself.

Comment: @Ed S. I'll try that as well. Seems like an easier solution, I thought the timer works somehow in a "neater" way than the sleep() method does.

Comment: @Dex: I just don't see the point in launching a timer when the main thread has nothing at all to do.  Use a new thread when you need to perform an operation in tandem with whatever is going on in the main thread.  All you need is `void main(...) { while(true) { DoSomething(); if(someExitCondition) break; Sleep(srcInterval); } }`