# Prevent the console from closing while debugging

Tags: c#, timer

My problem is that the console should stay opened. The timer cannot write anything into the console while Console.ReadLine() waits for an input. How do I prevent the console from closing without using Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadKey() or system("pause")?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Closer {
    public static class Program {
        public static void Main () {
            // Define timer
            var t = new Windows.Forms.Timer() {
                Enabled = true,
                Interval = 30000
            };

            // Give timer the tick function
            t.Tick += (object tSender, EventArgs tE) => {
                // If it is half past eleven
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() == "2330") {
                    // Close all osu!.exe's --- works
                    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("osu!")) {
                        p.Kill();
                    }

                    // Write a msg
                    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                }
            };

            // Prevent the console from closing --- Here's the problem
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014165/how-to-keep-a-windows-application-alive-in-c

Comment: It seems there is some problem with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. I updated my answer with `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: The problem isn't with the Windows Forms timer, but rather with the way you were trying to use it. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` expects to be used in a Windows Form application. More specifically, there has to be a Windows message loop running. That doesn't happen in a Console application. You'll notice that `System.Timers.Timer`, your program works just fine with the `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: @JimMischel You shouldn't change the code in the OP like that.  The specific problem here is because he's using the winforms timer.  Changing his code to be a different timer and thus fixing the problem invalidates the question.  You should post it as an answer, rather than an edit to the question.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for pointing that out. I misread the comment from Imran, saying that he had changed the code. For some reason I thought that the OP had said that *he* changed the code. Man, my face is red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `System.Timers.Timer` and everything works fine.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Define timer
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer()
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = 1000
        };

        // Give timer the tick function
        t.Elapsed += (object tSender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs tE) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        };


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: +1. You can replace that `Thread.Sleep` with a `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation as to why the winform timer won't work while this one will.

Comment: @Servy You are right... but I don't know the reason why it doesn't work :( I guess `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` works properly in Windows Forms Application as pointed by @Jim Mischel

Comment: It works!! Is the difference between System.Window.Forms.Timer and System.Timers.Timer really so big?

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating *two* problems.  Yes, an early release of .NET 4.5 made the mistake of having Console.ReadLine() take a lock that prevented threads from writing to the console.  That was fixed, just turn on Windows Update to get the service release.

But the *real* problem is your Timer class selection.  A System.Windows.Forms.Timer requires a message loop to get the Tick event to fire.  You can only get a message loop by calling Application.Run().  A very suitable replacement for Console.ReadLine() btw, use Application.ExitThread() to get your app to terminate.

You should use System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer in a console mode app.  Their callback is fired on a threadpool thread so don't require a dispatcher loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
```

I know this is stupid, but this does what you need. And the process will never terminate (itself) you've to kill manually.

Comment: @Imran I thought OP is using `Timers.Timer`, you covered the other part.but still failed to explain why it works?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't know the exact reason why `Forms.Timer` doesn't work in a Console Application. A possible reason was explained by @Jim Mischel in his comments.

Comment: @Imran Reason is `Forms.Timer` will be fired in Main thread which is actually blocked and timer never gets fired where as `Timers.Timer` works because it uses `ThreadPool` Thread which is independent of Main thread